# jquery can't find firebreath object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firebreath

I'm creating a web video player using Firebreath to compile my C/C++ codec as a browser plugin. Now the plugin is loaded OK and works (start, stop video etc.). The next step would be to implement full screen which would require to change the width and height of the plugin object (plus other stuff of course), but jQuery seems unable to find it.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="player0" class="playerUI ui-draggable">
    <object id="plugin0" type="application/x-webplayer" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">
    </object><br>
</div>
```

I would like to dynamically resize the object but when I try both

```
jQuery("#plugin0")
```

and

```
document.getElementById("#plugin0")
```

I get `[]` (null I would guess)

If I try `jQuery('object')` I get `[TypeError]`

On the other hand if I try to handle `player0` with jQuery everything works fine. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: wrap code inside `$(window).load(function(){ //code });`

Comment: OK but how can I do so if I want to call jQuery("plugin0") on a user's interaction? (button click).
Can I call your code within a JS function?

Comment: Btw, it should be `document.getElementById("plugin0")` (without the pound sign).  Also, you should just use FBVLC and save yourself the time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a lot of reasons why, but jquery doesn't work well when wrapped around a firebreath plugin object tag; I spent about 8 hours working on this issue once and eventually determined that it wasn't a big enough deal to keep working on.  I recommend you just don't do this. IF you need to move or position it, make it 100% x 100% and put it in a div and move that, it'll save you a lot of grief.

Comment: I hate this answer. =..[  I discovered this shortcoming of FB earlier today at work.  I just got settled at home and started Googling some more, and now this fresh 4-hour-old answer is making me face reality.  Aside from jQuery events not working (something I could live with), I noticed that the inability to select the `object` element via jQuery selector `#plugin0` and the throwing "Type Error" is only an NPAPI thing (Chrome/FireFox).  Is there an issue on GitHub that we could start a bounty on?

Comment: I actually noticed the error because I was trying to use FBVLC in an AngularJS application.  It seems that the `object` tag in Chrome/FireFox stops acting like an `object` tag once you set the `type` attribute to a firebreath type.  Not only do you get `TypeError` when you `console.log(document.getElementById('plugin'))`, but at least the `nodeName` attribute is not set: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3309 ... I imagine it's not as easy as "making the object element act more like an object element" though, eh?

Comment: You're welcome to try to fix it =] But trust me, it's more trouble than it's worth, which is why I haven't fixed it yet. Also please note that this isn't necessarily a bug in firebreath so much as an unfortunate interaction between jquery and npapi in general; most npapi plugins will likely have the same issue

Comment: Thank you Taxilian, I can confirm that in the end the best solution is to include the object in a div and manipulate the div.